# How to use the newest ipython in ubuntu12.04?

Tags: python

How to use the newest ipython in ubuntu12.04?

The newest ipython is 1.0. The ipython in official software center is too old.

Thanks

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use setuptools or pip. These usually get the latest version of any python package listed on [PyPi](https://pypi.python.org)

Try

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip          # or python-setuptools
sudo pip install ipython
```

Comment: +1. Using `pip` is indeed the way to install Python packages from PyPI. Also consider installing it in the user's home directory rather than system wide (less harmful in general - although ipython isn't likely to break things) by using `pip install --upgrade --user packagename`. It will then install it to `~/.local/bin` which is in the `PYTHONPATH` on Ubuntu.

Comment: I second the `--user` flag when using pip. Especially for packages that interact directly with the operating system and its libraries eg. PIL. This avoids breaking anything which depends on certain versions on libraries by not installing it system-wide.

Comment: `pip install --upgrade --user ipython` will remove old ipython in system. Is it safe ?

Comment: @waterloo2005 No, it won't remove any `ipython` from the system, nor will the regular `sudo pip install packagename` do. DPKG/APT installs in a different location, that had precedence over it. That makes running `ipython` or `import packagename` look first in the locations where `pip` installs. If you remove the `pip` package again, e.g. `sudo pip uninstall packagename` (or the user-equivalent), then you'll be using the older Ubuntu packaged version again. **So, yes, it is totally safe.** Yet, I recommend using `--user` without sudo if you only use it for that user account.

Comment: I will create a more canonical Q&A on Python packages installation using DPKG/APT together with the `pip` method in a few days if I can't find one.

Comment: You might also consider first creating a `virtualenv` so that the updated libraries live in their own namespace.

Answer (score 18):

```
sudo pip install --upgrade ipython
```

Comment: Good answer, not sure why downvoted